# How to override views-exposed-form in a module?

Tags: views, forms

I'm trying to override views-exposed-form. It works fine in a theme, but it's strange in a module. Eventually, it does find the template, but the form is available as `{{ element }}` and is missing the actual form tag - it's just the children.

`<form>{{ element }}</form>` sort of works.

In my module, I have

```
function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_form(array $variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#form_id'] == 'views_exposed_form') {
    return ['form__my_views_exposed_form'];
  }
  return [];
}

function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  
  $incfile = '../../../../../'.\Drupal::service('module_handler')
      ->getModule('views')
      ->getPath().'/views.theme.inc';

  return [
    'form__my_views_exposed_form' => [
      'template' => 'my-views-exposed-form',
      'path' => $path . '/theme/templates',
      'file' => $incfile,
      'render element' => 'form',
      'base hook' => 'form'
    ],
  ];
}
```

The `file` is taken from the views module .. the `render element` and `base hook` don't actually seem to matter much.

What am I missing ?